# AppDelegate: Show blocking view when something changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, appdelegate

I want something similar as the view shown in the "Friends" app when the iPhone is in flight mode. So my app shouldn't be usable when there is no internet and/or GPS so an empty view with an info message should pop up telling this the user. And of course vanish as soon as the internet/GPS is recovered. How can I do this?

EDIT: I know the reachabiljty class I only wonder how can I show and hide a view created in Storyboard directly from the app delegate?

Comment: Try using Reachability Class.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean I have problems finding out if internet is lost etc. my problem is how and where to show and hide this "block" view with the info label?

Comment: if your problem is related to showing view controller as custom alert view
you can try this [ViewControllerAlertView](https://github.com/ratulSharker/ViewController-Alert-View)